# Проблемы с парсером

Tags: python, парсер

Хочу запарсить инфу со страницы. Не сильно разбираюсь в коде сайта, поэтому просьба подсказать, Выдаёт пустоту.

```
r = requests.get('https://vk.com/raftaliyalu')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select('html'):
    friend = el.select(".page_counter")
print(f"{friend}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если попробовать ввести `curl.exe https://vk.com/raftaliyalu` в командной строке, то вывод будет пуст. То есть сайт просто закрывает запрос (его сокет) без отправки http разметки.

Но если добавить к запросу заголовок user-agent (можно взять из своего браузера), то он отправит http разметку. Например, `curl.exe -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36" https://vk.com/raftaliyalu`.

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-headers-to-requests-module) о добавлении заголовков в requests.

Comment: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' - пишет данную ошибку